# Как правильно создать проект 'ASP.NET Core MVC' + 'React'

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc

Есть готовый проект ASP.NET Core MVC. Попросили переделать, чтобы на фронтенде был Реакт.

Соответственно, вопрос: можно ли к имеющемуся проекту прикрутить Реакт? Если нельзя, то какой шаблон в VS выбирать при создании?

Comment: можно..........

Comment: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). | В MVC контроллер возвращает View. В SPA контроллер возвращает _данные_ (чаще всего в виде JSON), а отображаются эти данные с помощью JS (React и прочие либы).

Comment: К готовому проекту с ASP.NET MVC прикрутить React не получится. Зато можно будет сделать на основе логики готового проекта с MVC ,  [REST full Web API по шаблону из .NET](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9tfuEucw9-mValqMeOE3n4) , а затем сделать SPA на React или другом фреймворке

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Эта коллаборация (.NET MVC + ReactJS) возможна только для SPA?